# Position of views on the screen

Tags: android, position, scrollview, screen, detection

How to detect if cardview located in scrollview(linearlayout) went beyond the screen Or returned back to the field of view?
 I tried to do this through OnScrollChanged But it seems to me that this is not the case, and it is impossible to get the correct algorithm of work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the method `getLocalVisibleRect()` on your `CardView`:

```
Rect scrollViewRect = new Rect();
// Get the visible Rect of the ScrollView.
scrollView.getHitRect(scrollViewRect);
// Check if CardView's Rect is inside it.
if (!cardView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollViewRect)) {
    // The CardView is not visibile anymore.
}
```

You can place this code wherever you want to check if the `CardView` is not visible anymore on the screen.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer, I did all that I needed with your answer 